# How To Scale A Layout While Keep Its Children Original Scale

Tags: android, animation, scale

Can I Scale A Layout(e.g LinearLayout) from 0.5 to 1.0 while Keeping the size And position of the TextView inside the layout to 1.0 During the whole transformation (the overflow parts should hidden)?

I see That The Scale Animation in IOS Keep the scale of the Children And How Can I Achieve this in Android ?

Plus,On Starting Animation, The Parent Layout of the animated block has already make space for it,But in IOS ,the parent makes room gradually during the animation, does it have an option for me to do the same thing in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily with the Property Animation API.

havent tried it on LinearLayout but if the view children are ordered correctly with their "layout_width" & "layout_height" you can use the ValueAnimator class to scale the parent view via LayoutParams.width & height.

Only setback is API 11 and above.